# Apache Camel, send message when server starts and stops

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have a simply camel MINA server using the JAVA DSL, and I am running like the example documented here:

- [Running Camel standalone and have it keep running in JAVA](http://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone-and-have-it-keep-running.html)
- [MINA 2 Component](http://camel.apache.org/mina2.html)

Currently this server receives reports from a queue, updates them, and then sends them away to the next server. A very simple code:

```
public class MyApp_B {

    private Main main;

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        MyApp_B loadbalancer = new MyApp_B();
        loadbalancer.boot();
    }

    public void boot() throws Exception {
        main = new Main();
        main.enableHangupSupport();

        main.addRouteBuilder(
                new RouteBuilder(){
                    @Override
                    public void configure() throws Exception {
                        from("mina:tcp://localhost:9991")
                        .setHeader("minaServer", constant("localhost:9991"))
                        .beanRef("service.Reporting", "updateReport")
                        .to("direct:messageSender1");

                        from("direct:messageSender1")
                        .to("mina:tcp://localhost:9993")
                        .log("${body}");
                    }
                }
        );

        System.out.println("Starting Camel MyApp_B. Use ctrl + c to terminate the JVM.\n");
        main.run();
    }
}
```

Now, I would like to know if it is possible to do two things:

1. Make this server send a message to a master server when it starts running. This is an "Hello" message with this server's information basically.
2. Tell the master server to forget him when I shut it down pressing CTRL+C or doing something else.

I have also read this:

- http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/support/ServiceSupport.html#doStart%28%29

technically, by overriding the doStart and doStop methods I should get the intended behavior, however, those methods (specially the doStop method) don't work at all.

Is there a way to do this ? If yes how? If not, what are my options?

Thanks in advance, Pedro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code does work properly after all. The problem is my IDE, Eclipse. When using the **Terminate** button, Eclipse simply kills the process instead of send the CTRL+C signal to it. Furthermore it looks like Eclipse has no way of being able to send a CTRL+C signal to a process running on its console.

I have also created a discussion on Eclipse's official forums:

- http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1176961/#msg_1176961

And may it some day help some one in a situation similar to mine.

Comment: Good to know about this problem. Something like this can drive you mad.